# Load image from content as IImageProvider

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'd like to blend two images together using the Nokia Imaging SDK on WP8. For this, I need to set the blendFilter.ForegroundSource to an image type derived from IImageProvider.
I tried using

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/images/background.jpg", UriKind.Relative);  
var imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
blendFilter.ForegroundSource = new BitmapImageSource(imgSource);
```

but BitmapImage does not implement IReadableBitmap.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using StorageFileImageSource?

```
string imageFile = @"images\background.jpg"
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
blendFilter.ForegroundSource = new StorageFileImageSource(file))
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. I keep getting confused by all the image formats, streams etc.